# Positivity of linear combination of gaussian variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, gaussian, random-functions

Consider a collection of independent standard Gaussian variables $w_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, N$. Define its linear combination $f:=\sum_{i=1}^Na_iw_i+b_i$, where $a_i=pb_i$ ($p$ is a fixed parameter), its expectation $\mu:=\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i>0$. And from this we have $\sigma^2:=p^2\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^2$.

**My question is:** Derive a lower bound on $$\mathbb{P}(f>0)>g(\mu,\sigma^2) \text{ (or}\geq)$$

I would need the bound $g(\mu,\sigma^2)$ to be sensitive to the mean and variance of $f$. Consequently, a trade-off between the mean and variance arises, leading to the following observations:

(1) When the variance is fixed, a larger mean corresponds to a larger probability $\mathbb{P}(f > 0)$.

(2) When the mean is fixed, a smaller variance corresponds to a larger probability $\mathbb{P}(f > 0)$.

I appreciate any insights, references, or techniques that can shed light on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually not what you want. I have problems understanding your question. Let $b := \sum_{i=1}^n b_i > 0$ and $c^2 := \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$. Then $f \sim \mathcal{N}(b,p^2 \cdot c^2)$, thus $q := \mathbb{P}(f > 0) = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{-b}{pc} \right)$ with $\Phi$ the distribution funtion of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. We get $\frac{-b}{pc} = \Phi^{-1}(1-q)$ and $p = \frac{-b}{c\Phi^{-1}(1-q)}$. Since $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ are well known, what is the problem?

Comment: (I found involving $p$ is misleading, I have delete $p$ in my original question.)

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Maybe you are working with an erroneous equation: $\mathbb{P}(f > 0) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(f > 2b)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(f<0)$ is equal to $\mathbb{P}(f>2b)$, since $f$ is $\mathcal{N}(b,p^2c^2)$ and its symmetric to $x=b$ am I right?

Comment: yes you are right. But I still don't know why are you working with estimates and not with the exact expression. $\Phi$ is monotone with the consequence thart you can easily convert any bound for the probability into bounds for the coefficients $a,b,c,\ldots$.

Comment: sorry, just one second ago I found my question does not make sense. I will revise again

Comment: Possibly you are misled by a "false friend": the word "eventually" in English does not mean the same thing that "eventuell" means in French and German.

Comment: @DieterKadelka sorry it took a while. My goal is to derive the probability $X>0$, which is strictly positive, not nonnegative. But to calculate the integral $\int_{0,\infty}pdf dx$ would give probability $P(X\geq 0)$.